# readlink unable to take path names mentioned in a file

Tags: bash, readlink

```
while
    read -r line 
        do  
           readlink -f $line > a.txt 
done < $1
```

I have a file which contains 30 symbolic destination pathnames passed by $1. I want to read this file line by line and wants to save ls results of each path in a file a.txt. The problem coming is that its only taking last path name mentioned in $1. Its ignoring upper 29 lines. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
readlink -f $line > a.txt
```

to

```
readlink -f "$line" >> a.txt
```

> The >> appends to a file or creates the file if it doesn't exist.
>
> The > overwrites the file if it exists or creates it if it doesn't exist.

https://serverfault.com/a/196735

Comment: Thanks sir. it worked!!! Thank you so much. :) I would like to give you reputation but cant give. :(

Comment: Or better yet put the redirect outside the loop `done >a.txt`

Comment: ... and fix the quoting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: I can't delete anything but you should be able to delete it yourself. I marked it as a duplicate for the time being.